# How to pass custom date format to CsvProvider in F#

Tags: f#

I'm using [CsvProvider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) to parse a CSV file i receive from an external source. The date format of the file is dd/MM/yy. But CsvProvider infers it as MM/dd/yy and get all dates wrong.

Is there any way I can pass the dateformat to CsvProvider?

I can read the dates as string and then convert them using Seq.Map to Datetime (which is two steps).

I'm trying to find out if i can do in a single step

**Example**

csv file sample.csv is having data like below

```
11/01/90
12/01/90
13/01/90
14/01/90
15/01/90
```

I'm using the below F# code

```
type MyCsvProvider = CsvProvider<Sample= "sample.csv", HasHeaders=false, Schema="Date (date)">
MyCsvProvider.Load("sample.csv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CsvProvider` type provider does not have a way of explicitly specifying a format for parsing dates, so if you have some completely non-standard format, you'll just have to read it as `string` (which is what CSV provider infers if it cannot parse dates automatically) and then parse the date values explicitly.

That said, you can specify the `Culture` parameter, which makes it possible to parse dates in format that is common in countries outside of the US. For example, your date format would work fine with the `en-GB` culture (in the UK, you first write day, then month and then year).

In the following small example, the `Test` property is inferred as `DateTime`:

```
type A = CsvProvider<"""Test
11/01/90
12/01/90
13/01/90
14/01/90
15/01/90""",Culture="en-GB">

let r = A.GetSample().Rows |> Seq.head
r.Test
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I will live with your solution this as there is no better option.